# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock doesnt find my function ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I have a masterpage , i use Baslik.aspx and there are my scripts in Baslik.aspx page.

I want to call a function in Baslik.aspx from code behind.I can see my functions on firebug console.how can fix it ?

this is call function in cs :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "test", string.Format("SetPageWidth('{0}');", widthValue), true);
```

this is my Baslik.aspx code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server
.
.
.
    <script type="text/javascript">   
   .
   .
   .
     function SetPageWidth(width) {
            console.log(width);
            $('.page').css("width", width);
            $('body').css("height", "auto");
        }
   </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for any JavaScript error?

Comment: doesnt find my SetPageWidth function

Comment: Did you check for errors in the` FireBug Console` ?

Comment: There is no error , scriptmanager cant access my local functions.

Comment: Will it be possible to explain in JsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "test", string.Format("SetPageWidth('{0}');", widthValue), true);
```